# Copying over NTFS ACL's from one offline server to another server

Tags: active-directory, windows, access-control-list, file-permissions

We have two machines on the same domain: Machine A (Windows 2003) and Machine B (Windows 2003). Both have a set of files that are identical and have been kept identical by a scheduled process. However, the Machine A is now offline (i.e., not on the network but I still have physical access to the machine) and we realize that the ACL's were not identical.

What would be the most elegant way to copy over the ACL's with Machine A being offline?

Comment: When you say Machine A is offline, do you mean that it is gone or that it is merely powered down and can be brought back up if needed?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it is not longer on the network. However, I do have access to the actual machine. Just won't be able to connect between machines. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset is identical on both machines, except for the ACL, you could do:

```
icacls c:\path\to\data\* /save ACLData /T
```

Copy the "ACLData" file to the destination machine, and then:

```
icacls c:\path\to\data /restore ACLData
```

This will replicate the ACLs (and just the ACLs) assuming the data structure is identical, and you have the rights to do so.

Comment: This seems like the way to go! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET SOURCEFOLDER=\\server\share\folder
SET DESTFOLDER=C:\folder

REM copy all security ACLs
ROBOCOPY "%SOURCEFOLDER%" "%DESTFOLDER%" /IS /E /COPY:S /NDL /TEE /LOG+:C:\temp\robocopy.log
```

/IS - include "same" files
/E - copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
/COPY:S - copy NTFS acls
/TEE - output to screen and log file
/NDL - don't include directory name in log
/LOG+: append to log file

You may need to use quotes if the folders have spaces in the names.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly `xcopy` with `/o` could do this for you.

Comment: Sorry about my question not being clear enough. I tried to explain what I meant by offline. Now about using `xcopy`, from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx, `Copies file ownership and discretionary access control list (DACL) information.` I'm not sure how that would help. I'd need a way to export it from Machine A and import it to Machine B.